# Page layout bug

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

Every now and then, the layout of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315131/microsoft-internal-property-this-property-does-not-have-a-setter) gets messed up in my IE9 browser (but not Firefox) on Windows 7, Standards mode, 100% zoom: the content is shifted to the right and appears underneath the advertising. Other questions seem to be fine.

**UPDATE:** I think this is a bug in IE. I examined the page using Developer Tools, and it appears that even though the vote buttons and question are in adjacent `<td>` cells, IE thinks there's an extra `<td>` between them. You can see in the screenshot below how the blank space is precisely the width of the comments area.

[image]

Comment: Using IE 9 on Windows 7 - cannot reproduce. Are you using an ad blocker?

Comment: I don't have an ad blocker. I was able to reproduce the issue consistently for a couple minutes, even after restarting the browser, but not anymore. Perhaps the comments that people have been adding somehow fixed the problem.

Comment: Er... now the problem is back.

Comment: Still not seeing it. Is Java enabled?

Comment: I don't have Java installed.

Comment: The bug seems to come and go. Maybe if you restarted your browser?

Comment: Do you have any user scripts stack apps installed? I am restarting IE for pretty much every page view.

Comment: I've never installed any.

Comment: I will have to leave this as [meta-tag:status-norepro] - whatever I do, I can't get this. Does this still happen after a reboot?

Comment: I rebooted, and the problem didn't occur the first time I went to the page, but the problem came back after that.

Comment: What are the steps for reproduction? I go to the page, refresh it a few times and see nothing.

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen just by refreshing the page. After restarting IE, I go to stackoverflow.com, click "meta" in the top nav bar, find this question, click the link in the post... and it doesn't happen the first time. Then I click "meta", find this question, etc., and after a few cycles it heppens.

Comment: Went through this cycle a good dosen times - no repro.

Comment: @Oded: This is probably a bug in IE. So I guess this question can be closed?

Comment: No need to close. The [meta-tag:status-norepro] marks this already.